# Android build system reports: "trouble writing output: shouldn't happen"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After making some changes to an internally-developed library (which is published on a Maven repository hosted on Bitbucket), I tried to update an Android application to use the new version of the library. After increasing the version of the library dependency in the application build file, Gradle was unable to generate the APK, falling short on some dex-related task (it was `preDexDebug` on version 1.2.3 of the build system, it is `transformClassesWithDexForDebug` on 1.5.0). More specifically, the reported error is:

```
trouble writing output: shouldn't happen
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Yes, *specifically* was ironic. I suppose this is not a problem of exceeding 65K methods, because [the message would indeed be more specific](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) than "shouldn't happen". And I already had duplicated versions of `support-v4` before (coming from Facebook SDK, the Android Support Design library, and the like) when everything just worked. So, what else could it be?

Comment: It's strange... I'm almost sure this is not a problem of exceeding 65K methods, I had to decrease again the version of the library dependency and report an error in AndroidStudio reports... if I get an answer, I will write because it was impossible to me fixed this issue..

Comment: @Aspicas unfortunately it is not an issue related to Android Studio. It's related to the build system (which can even be invoked on the command line by using e.g. `gradlew`) and, at least in my case, more specifically to the way Java code is translated into the DEX format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is a generic method.

More precisely, it appears that generic methods are not able to access `static` `final` fields in the body of an `else` clause. By that, I mean that the Android build system is not able to correctly transform such occurrences in the DEX format. Of course, everything is fine when you build, because `javac` is used. When DEX is involved, however, that limitation pops up, with an incomprehensible and appalling error message. What really *shouldn't happen* is having developers mess with a sophisticated language such as Java without knowing what nonsense they are doing.

Just for those who still hardly believe the DEX format has been crippled so much w.r.t. Java 5 features (not even 6, or 7, or 8... that stuff belongs to Java 5 I believe) let me just show you an example. In my library, I had the following:

```java
    private static final String TAG = MyClass.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public <T> T getValue(String key, Class<T> type) {
        String value = null;
        if (data.containsKey(key)) {
            value = data.get(key);
        } else {
            String message = "Error getting a configuration value with key: " + key;
            Log.e(TAG, message);
            return null;
        }
        // ...
    }
```

and the dreaded "shouldn't happen" error message kept on raising its ugly head up. However, just by inverting the `if` condition:

```java
    @Override
    public <T> T getValue(String key, Class<T> type) {
        String value = null;
        if (!data.containsKey(key)) {
            String message = "Error getting a configuration value with key: " + key;
            Log.e(TAG, message);
            return null;
        } else {
            value = data.get(key);
        }
        // ,,,
    }
```

I was able to make the error disappear.